# Flutter Dart version not upgrading to 2.9.0

Tags: flutter, dart

i created a flutter project on my Windows PC and when i run the flutter doctor command, it says my dart version is 2.9.0.

i'm trying to run the project on macOS to test the project on iPhone. However, i'm not able to run flutter pub get. on my flutter doctor on mac, it says the dart version is 2.1.0, although i installed dart version 2.9.2 and switched to it.

but the version on flutter is not changing. i ran flutter upgrade and flutter upgrade --force and its still the same.

any ideas?

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel master
Flutter 1.22.0-10.0.pre.82 • channel master •
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 9248fda410 (11 hours ago) • 2020-09-03 16:08:01 -0700
Engine • revision 3f05b521b9
Tools • Dart 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-86.0.dev)
```

when i run flutter pub get, i get the following error:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.5.0.                                  
                                                                        
Because flutter_auth depends on webview_flutter >=0.3.20+1 which requires SDK version >=2.7.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
```

when switching to channel stable:

```
git: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
git:    dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/macrobenchmarks/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/platform_views_layout/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/platform_views_layout_hybrid_composition/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/test_apps/stocks/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/bots/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/devicelab/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/android_embedding_v2_smoke_test/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/android_splash_screens/splash_screen_kitchen_sink/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/android_splash_screens/splash_screen_trans_rotate/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/android_views/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/channels/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/external_ui/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/flavors/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/flutter_driver_screenshot_test/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/flutter_gallery/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/hybrid_android_views/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/image_loading/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/ios_platform_view_tests/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/platform_interaction/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/release_smoke_test/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/ui/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/manual_tests/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/tools/pubspec.yaml
git:    examples/catalog/pubspec.yaml
git:    examples/hello_world/pubspec.yaml
git:    examples/platform_channel/pubspec.yaml
git:    examples/platform_channel_swift/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/flutter/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/flutter_driver/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/flutter_goldens/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/flutter_localizations/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/flutter_tools/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/fuchsia_remote_debug_protocol/pubspec.yaml
git: Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
git: Aborting
Switching channels failed with error code 1.
```

Comment: Change your channel to stable instead of master and upgrade flutter: `flutter channel stable && flutter upgrade`

Comment: @Owczar i updated the question  what i get when  i try to switch channels

Comment: Ughh. The best solution is to remove flutter and dart from the hard drive.
You can check paths of flutter and dart by this command: `which flutter dart`. After you remove everything, install the newest flutter (it contains the newest Dart) again: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Answer (score -2):

This simply means that you might accidentally have modified some file from the Flutter SDK. To know the modification, navigate to the location where you have Flutter SDK installed, and enter the command `git status` and you will see the name of the files in red color that have been modified. Then, try to run the following in your Flutter install directory:

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

See also [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9218) for issues related to this.